# When we do not have execute permission on current directory, why does "cd .." work?

Tags: linux, unix, file-permissions

Let's say we have a directory called foo: `/home/user/foo`. After I `cd` to foo I change execute permission for current directory: `chmod -x ../foo`. After removing execute permission I cannot access any files, which is normal. But when I write "`cd ..`", I can change directory. Why does "`cd ..`" work?

Comment: I don't agree that this is off topic. It's relevant to shell scripting, which is a kind of programming.

Answer (score 4):

At least in bash, `cd ..` is implemented specially. It doesn't read the `..` directory from the current directory; rather, it computes the name of the parent directory by removing the trailing component.

Quoting `builtins/cd.def` from the bash 4.3 sources:

> The default is to follow symbolic links, as if `-L' were specified.`
>   ..' is processed by removing the immediately previous pathname
>   component back to a slash or the beginning of DIR.

You can see this as part of the output of `help cd`.

This help text seems to have been introduced in bash 4.3, but the functionality goes back at least to bash 3.2.

Other shells may or may not behave the same way.

Comment: You are right, thanks. In bash if we use cd with -P option, then everything looks normal.